# php select from database not show the correct result

Tags: php, mysql

this is my code for display the data i wan from database but when i select from 2 condition it no showing anything

```
<form action="sebelum_tempah.php" method="post" >
    <div align="center"><span class="style16 style17">Enter I/C Number</span>
        <input name="noic" type="text" size="15" value="" id="" />
        </span>
        <input name="Submit10" type="submit" class="style16" value="SAH" />
    </div>
    <label>
    <div align="center"><br />
        <br />
    </div>
    </label>
    <table width="500" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
      <tr bgcolor="#FF6600">
        <th width="117" bgcolor="#006699" scope="row">Name</th>
        <th width="73" bgcolor="#006699" scope="row">No I/C </th>
        <th width="80" bgcolor="#006699" scope="row">No Phone </th>
        <th width="110" bgcolor="#006699" scope="row">Please click below</th>
      </tr>
      <?php 
include "conn.php";
if($_POST){
$sql= "SELECT bil,noic,nama,notel FROM user WHERE noic='_POST[noic]'";
$result=mysql_query($sql,$db_conn);
$i=0;
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

$i++;                                           
?>

      <tr>
       <th scope="row"><?php echo $row{'nama'};?></th>
        <th scope="row"><?php echo $row{'noic'}; ?></th>
        <th scope="row"><?php echo $row{'notel'}; ?></th>
        <th scope="row"><a href="semasa_tempah.php?bil=<?php echo $row['bil'];?>" target="_self">Reserve</a></th>
    </tr>
      <?php }
}
mysql_close($db_conn);
?>
    </table>

  </form>
```

i get the result but i wan when 2 condition meet like the noic is the person name

```
$sql= "SELECT bil,noic,nama,notel FROM user WHERE noic='_POST[noic]' AND nama='_POST[nama]'";
```

not display anything

Comment: Is it a typo or is the $ sign in front of _POST removed?

Comment: And show the form where you have the two fields you are using in the conditions.

Comment: What do u want to be returned from ur query ? Could u say it with words plz ? Because ur name_fields doesn't mean anything to me (i mean if noic is the last name - does nama is first name?)

Comment: Stop using mysql_* functions, it has been deprecated for good reasons. Prefer prepared statements.

Comment: Try to split php code from html code next time.

Comment: sry, miss type $, in my coding have $, i wan call the data by noic and nama, dunno how to do it

Answer (score 0):

Do following changes and try.

```
$sql= "SELECT bil,noic,nama,notel FROM user WHERE noic='$_POST[noic]'";



<tr>
       <th scope="row"><?php echo $row['nama'];?></th>
        <th scope="row"><?php echo $row['noic']; ?></th>
        <th scope="row"><?php echo $row['notel']; ?></th>
        <th scope="row"><a href="semasa_tempah.php?bil=<?php echo $row['bil'];?>" target="_self">Reserve</a></th>
    </tr>
```